# How to: Vue3 Setup composition API - Declare typescript type of a object ref

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Using Vue 3 and composition API with Setup syntax (TypeScript), I would like to declare a ref inside a component detailing informations of an user.

```
const userData: Ref<User | undefined> = ref({} as User)
```

if I use this syntax, I have to put all the time a "?" after userData when I want to access if because the data can also be undefined.

```
<template>
  <div class="pa-4 pt-1">
    <HeaderPage :title="`Administrateurs - ${userData?.email}`" />
    aaaa {{ userData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import HeaderPage from '@/components/pages/Header.vue'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import UserService from '@/api/modules/user'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

import type { Ref } from 'vue'
import type { User } from '@/api/types/user.interfaces'

const route = useRoute()

const loading = ref(false)
const userData: Ref<User | null> = ref({} as User)

onMounted(() => {
  fetchUserData()
})

function fetchUserData() {
  UserService.getUser(route.params.userId as string).then((res) => {
    userData.value = res
    loading.value = false
  })
}
</script>
```

---

**EDIT**
tried this:

```
const userData: Ref<User> = ref()
```

but I got:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow userData to be undefined

```js
const userData = ref<User>() // implicit undefined allowed
const userDate = ref<User |  undefined>() // or explicit
```

Only render the component when data is defined

```html
<HeaderPage v-if="userData" :title="`Administrateurs - ${userData.email}`" />
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this, but I also got a typescript error (please, see the original post, I edited)

Comment: @Jer I made a mistake, see the edit: `const userData = ref<User>()`

Comment: Thanks but I made it work with that: const userData: Ref<User | undefined> = ref({} as User) but it's the same thing I guess

Comment: Initiating as `{}` would not make it undefined. I would recommend against that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this.

```js
const userData = ref<User>();
```

But still, use `<div v-if="userData" ...>` in template

Answer (score 0):

try this in script

```
const userData: Ref<User | undefined> = ref()
```

and in template

```
 <div v-if="userData" class="pa-4 pt-1">
  <HeaderPage :title="`Administrateurs - ${userData.email}`" />
   aaaa {{ userData }}
 </div>
```

so now the userData is undefined at starting so nothing will be displayed but when it will be fetched and set it won't be undefined and so the condition v-if='userData' will be satisfied and data will be displayed and therefore no optional chaining (userData?.email) is required in the template because now the typescript will know that user will be always present in div tag, thanks to v-if="userData" condition